# Free lecture notes to Carl Bender's Mathematical Physics video lecture course?

Tags: reference-request, asymptotics, mathematical-physics

I am just watching Carl Bender's Mathematical Physics video lecture course (about asymptotics and its application in physics)

http://www.perimeterscholars.org/328.html

which is great!

Are there any lecture notes for this great course uploaded somewhere? After watching the videos, I'd like to reconsider the course in detail.

I Prof. Carl Bender has written a book about mathematical physics dealing with some of the methods he explains in the course, but I would prefer lecture notes that exactly follow this course first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This book:  Advanced Mathematical Methods for Scientists and Engineers: Asymptotic Methods and Perturbation Theory

[https://www.amazon.com/Advanced-Mathematical-Methods-Scientists-Engineers/dp/0387989315/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1491517097&sr=8-1&keywords=carl+bender](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387989315)

Comment: there are also some more or less legal djvu/pdf's out in the www...